# Can I route a local path to a remote path on OSX?

Tags: macos, routes, url-routing

is it possible to automatically route a local path like `localhost/pathToResource` to a remote source `<serverIP>/pathToResource` in OSX (Mountain Lion)?

As I understand, you cannot do this in the hosts file, because it only maps DNS names to IPs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a web server (assuming we're talking about HTTP requests) on `localhost` which redirects or proxies requests to `pathToResource` to the remote path. For example, create an .htaccess file in the document root of your web server (`~/Sites` for the built-in Apache server) with something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pathToResource$ http://<serverIp>/pathToResource [R]

# or

RewriteRule ^pathToResource$ http://<serverIp>/pathToResource [P]
```

The first rule will *redirect* any request to the remote URL (clients are instructed to visit the other URL), the second one will *proxy* it (get the data and return it as if the remote resource was hosted locally).

Comment: Hi deceze, using the redirect `[R]`works great! But when I change it to the proxy `[P]`then I get a 503 error. Any idea, what might cause that?

Comment: As an FYI: I have to use our company proxy to access the remote service. Could it be, that the OSX Apache doesn't use this proxy?

Comment: Maybe your Apache is not setup to proxy. Look at the error logs to figure out the real problem, it'll tell you.

Comment: Oh boy! We had company-wide domain migration few month in the past. The port for our remote response was blocked in the beginning and then opend on request. This is done in the company proxy, which is configured automatically for the Windows-PCs. But since I'm using a Mac and was not aware that this proxy even exist the remote service was still unreachable. Setting up the company proxy as `RemoteProxy` in the Apaches httpd.conf solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to decezes help, I got it working. However, I ended up not using the .htaccess and Apaches RewriteEngine, but configuring a `ProxyPass`and `ProxyPassReverse`in the `httpd.conf`.

```
ProxyRemote http http://<your-componay-proxy>
ProxyPass /service http://<remoteIP>:<port>/webservice.svc
ProxyPassReverse /service http://<remoteIP>:<port>/webservice.svc
```

This also works like a charm, but without the regexes.

But decezes answer is also working, so I marked his answer as correct.